# Show scanning progress while using FindFirstFile and FindNextFile

Tags: c++, qt, winapi

I'm making a UI virus scanning app. Now I want it to display the scanning progress from 0 to 100 and put it in a progress bar. Here's the code that I used to display all the files or folders that were choosen to scan.First is the class declaration.

```
#ifndef SCANTHREAD_H
#define SCANTHREAD_H

#include <QThread>
#include <QObject>
#include <QDebug>
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "stack.h"
class ScanThread : public QThread
{
   Q_OBJECT
public:
   ScanThread(MainWindow *mainWindow = NULL, std::string sFolderScan = "", QObject *parent = Q_NULLPTR);
~ScanThread();

   private:
     void run(void);
     void scanFolder(std::string sFolder);

   public slots:

   signals:
     void scanDone(QString data);
     void scanningFile(QString sFile);
   private:
     MainWindow *m_mainWindow;
     std::string m_sFolderScan;
     Stack *m_stack;
   public:
     int scannedFiles = 0;
     double progress;
   };

   #endif
```

Here's the scanthread.cpp file:

```
#include "scanthread.h"
ScanThread::ScanThread(MainWindow *mainWindow, std::string sFolderScan, QObject *parent):
    m_mainWindow(mainWindow),
    m_sFolderScan(sFolderScan)
{
    //m_mainWindow = mainWindow;
    //m_sFolderScan = sFolderScan;
m_stack = new Stack();
}

ScanThread::~ScanThread()
{
      delete m_stack;
}

void ScanThread::scanFolder(std::string sFolder)
{
     std::string sFolderFind;
     WIN32_FIND_DATAA   FindFileData;
HANDLE  hFind = INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE;
QString sFolderScan;

char* szPath = new char[MAX_PATH + 1];
ZeroMemory(szPath, MAX_PATH + 1);
strcpy_s(szPath, MAX_PATH,sFolder.c_str());

m_stack->Push(szPath);

while (!m_stack->isStackEmpty()) {
    szPath = m_stack->Pop();
    sFolderScan = szPath;
    sFolderFind = std::string(szPath) + "\\*.*";
    hFind = FindFirstFileA(sFolderFind.c_str(), &FindFileData);
    if (hFind == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
        delete[] szPath;
        szPath = NULL;
        continue;
    }
    do
    {
        if (FindFileData.dwFileAttributes & FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY)
        {
            std::string sFol = FindFileData.cFileName;
            if (sFol == "." || sFol == "..")
            {
                continue;
            }
            char* szPath2 = new char[MAX_PATH + 1];
            ZeroMemory(szPath2, MAX_PATH + 1);
            strcpy_s(szPath2, MAX_PATH, QString::fromStdString(sFolderScan.toStdString() + "\\" + FindFileData.cFileName).toStdString().c_str());
            m_stack->Push(szPath2);
        }
        else
        {
            emit scanningFile(QString::fromStdString(sFolderScan.toStdString() + "\\" + FindFileData.cFileName));
            scannedFiles++;
            progress = scannedFiles * 0.25;
        }
    }while (FindNextFileA(hFind, &FindFileData));
    FindClose(hFind);
    delete[] szPath;
    szPath = NULL;
}
if (!m_stack->isStackEmpty())
    m_stack->FreeStack();
}

void ScanThread::run(void)
{
    connect(this, SIGNAL(scanDone(QString)), m_mainWindow, SLOT(ScanDone(QString)));
    connect(this, SIGNAL(scanningFile(QString)), m_mainWindow, 
    SLOT(scanningFile(QString)));
    scanFolder(m_sFolderScan);
    this->exec();
}
```

So basically I created a stack and put all files and folders in it and pop it to display the files. Now I want it to display the scanning progress while it is being scanned. I have two variables named 'scannedFiles' and 'progress'. My first idea was update continuously these variables while the scanning thread is still running, but the results wasn't exactly the way I expected. The line 'progress = scannedFiles * 0.25' is just the line I use to test the code. First i wanted to count all the files in a folder or directory and then update continuously the scanned files, you don't have to care about that.

Comment: `but the results wasn't exactly the way I expected` what were you expecting? What did you see instead?

Comment: `ScanThread(MainWindow *mainWindow, ...)` - This is eventually going to break. UI elements are owned by a thread, and only the owning thread is allowed to make changes. You will have to devise a different communication strategy or get rid of the multithreading altogether.

Comment: @AlanBirtles I want it to display 0 to 100 while all the files are being scanned. Instead it just displays some random decimals